# Returning references with or without a function

Tags: php, syntax, return-by-reference

Are there any actual difference between the two ways to get the value by reference?

**Way 1**

```
<?php
class foo {
    public $value = 42;

    public function &getValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

$obj = new foo;
$myValue = &$obj->getValue();
// $myValue is a reference to $obj->value, which is 42.
$obj->value = 2;
echo $myValue;
// prints the new value of $obj->value, i.e. 2.
?>
```

**Way 2**

```
<?php
class foo {
    public $value = 42;
    public function getValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

$obj = new foo;
$myValue = &$obj->value;
$obj->value = 2;
echo $myValue; 
?>
```

In both cases *2* is printed. So why does one need the *getValue()* function then? The first example is taken from the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php).

Comment: The 3 rules of references in PHP are: Rule #1) Don't use references. Rule #2) Don't use references. Rule #3) Don't use references.

Comment: @Sherif Better not use objects then ;-)

Comment: @jeroen No idea why you would say that. Objects aren't references.

Comment: Make your $value property protected rather than public. Currently you can always set it directly. i.e. The example doesn't demonstrate anything useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the first approach if class fields don't have a modifier 'public'. In this case you can't get a reference to the field outside the class. See example:

```
<?php

class foo
{
    protected $value = 1;

    public function setValue($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function &getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

$obj = new foo;
$myValue = &$obj->getValue();
$obj->setValue(2);
echo $myValue;
?>
```

Comment: You definitely don't __need__ a reference _at all_ there even if the property visibility wasn't public. It will work just fine with a public setter/getter method. Using a reference there only serves to break your code and cause strange awkward difficult to debug bugs with no advantage whatsoever.

Comment: @Sherif It's not a question of necessity. It's explanation when the the first approach can be used. It's up to developer to use or to not.

Comment: The explanation is wrong, unfortunately. If you expect a developer to make an informed choice about what to use you need to actually explain what it does well. This explains nothing. It just portrays that _option 1_ is what _should_ be used, which is just pure advocating, not explaining.

Comment: I don't mean to come off as abrasive. So I'm sorry if I have, but what I'm stating isn't opinionated or subjective. It's based on concrete factual knowledge of how references work in PHP and first-hand experience of dealing with very difficult to debug code in PHP as a direct result of using references poorly where they weren't necessary or even helpful. I'm very passionate about steering people in the right direction when it comes to using PHP and I saw the OP's question as a perfect example of where one might be led astray if they are not thoroughly __informed__ of why this a bad choice here

Comment: Thank you, @andrej-ludinovskov! I think you explained what was asked, that is what one may use these kind of functions for.